# Meta viewport tag inside noscript block

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

I have an iPhone web application that creates a "meta viewport" tag dynamically, using Javascript, depending on certain user-configured settings.

I want to provide a default meta viewport tag in case Javascript is disabled, but can't find a proper way to do it.

I tried this:

```
<noscript>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
</noscript>
```

And it does work, however it does not seem to be valid, as `noscript` is apparently not allowed in the HEAD section of an HTML document (I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270478/valid-way-to-add-noscript-in-head-for-wrapping-redirect))

Any alternatives?

**Edit:**

I already tried having a default meta viewport tag, then *removing* (or replacing) it with Javascript. This "almost" works: You can indeed modify an existing viewport meta tag with Javascript (the technique is well described [here](http://quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2011/06/dynamically_cha.html)). However there are some limitations: While you can modify the value of a given property, you can NOT make the device "forget" (reset to default value) a property that has already been defined. Also, simply removing the meta tag with Javascript doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricky.

Have you tried

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">

<script>
document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=2.0">');
</script>
```

? (2.0 being the scale than you would want to set if scripting is enabled)

I can't find any binding info on whether this is legal, but it seems to be in HTML. The question is whether it'll be parsed correctly.

Other than that, I can think of only two alternatives:

- Detecting Javascript support on server side, and serving two different pages, one with, one without the meta tag
- Always embedding the viewport tag, and *removing* it using Javascript - I have no idea whether this'll work, though.

Comment: @Pekka: I actually tried the second approach before even thinking of noscript. However when a default meta viewport tag is included, and then removed/modified/replaced with Javascript, the iPhone will still use the original meta viewport definition :-(

Comment: @Pekka: How can I detect whether Javascript is enabled on the server side?

Comment: @Grodriguez what server side language(s) can you use?

Comment: @Grodriguez there are two methods I can think of: 1. Do a Javascript redirect when the user first enters your site, to a URL like `example.com/?javascript=yes` then store the information in the user's session on server side. 2. Use Javascript to set a cookie. On the next request, you can check server side whether the cookie is set.

Comment: @Pekka: I was hoping for a way to do this without involving an extra request, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Grodriguez I thought of another possibility, see update. It's untested

Comment: @Pekka: Thanks for the update; doesn't work though (same issues as when removing/replacing the meta tag via Javascript & DOM manipulation)

Comment: Just for completeness: It seems that you _can_ indeed modify an existing viewport meta tag with Javascript (the technique is well described here: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2011/06/dynamically_cha.html). However there are some limitations: While you can modify the value of a given property (as in Pekka's response), you can NOT "forget" (reset to default value) a property that has already been defined. Also, simply removing the meta tag with Javascript doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You could use HTML5. In HTML5 `<noscript>` is permitted as a child of head, and `<meta>` is permitted as a child of noscript.

See here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know noscript was permitted in the head section in HTML5. Sadly I cannot switch to HTML5 for this application.