# Is this trick safe to do in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, graceful-degradation

Is this safe to do in all browsers? It's a way to simply redirect users to a different place when js is off.

```
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://site.com/nojs">
</noscript
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270478/valid-way-to-add-noscript-in-head-for-wrapping-redirect

Comment: [build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer adding `no-js` class to `<html>` element. You may combine this trick with `ie-x` class.

For example:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->  <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
<!-- some meta tags --->
<script>
(function(doc) {
   doc.className = doc.className.replace(/(^|\b)no\-js(\b|$)/, 'js');
}(document.documentElement));
</script>
<!-- other script tags should be before </body> -->
```

You can read about it there: [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/#The-markup%E2%98%85no-js) and [here](http://paulirish.com/2009/avoiding-the-fouc-v3/)